# Python Dynamically Import Functions from Subdirectory

Tags: python, import, parameters, module, parameter-passing

I am trying to dynamically import functions from a module based on a parameter but can't quite figure it out. I have a handler function, then a subdirectory filled with files each containing one function I want to use. I'm using `import_module` from `importlib`, but it hasn't quite solved my problem.

My file structure is:

```
handler.py
functions
--__init__.py
--square.py
```

Here is my imported module (`square.py`):

```
def sq(param):
  return param*param
```

Here's my handler code:

```
from importlib import import_module

def main(fun):
  file = import_module(fun)
  result = fun.sq(4)
  print(result)
```

And I am calling my handler like: `main("functions.square")`

I want to call my handler like: `main("functions.square.sq")` so that my main function can look like:

```
from importlib import import_module

def main(fun):
  file = import_module(fun)
  result = fun(4)
  print(result)
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workaround by naming the main function of all the subfiles (like square) the same, naming them all `run()`. Therefore I could call them dynamically like this:

```
from importlib import import_module

def main(fun):
  result = import_module(fun).run(4)
  print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this, I was doing this through an AWS Lambda which caused additional problems. I fixed it like this:

```
from importlib import import_module

def main(fun):
  result = return import_module("src.main.functions." + fun).run(4)
  print(result)
```

My file structure looks like:

```
project
--| lambdas
----| src
------| main
--------| handler.py
--------| functions
----------| __init__.py
----------| square.py
```

Comment: I tried using a relative path and AWS was not a fan of that, so I did an absolute path.